# Joining parent rows to their children

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table consisting of parent to children mappings.

E.g

```
my_table
-----+------+---------
  id | name | child_id
-----+------+---------
  a  |  A1  | b
  b  |  B1  | c
  b  |  B2  | c
  b  |  B3  | a
  c  |  C1  | d
  d  |  D1  | a
  d  |  D2  | b
```

I would like to 'join' them so as to produce this output:
(Rows marked with '<--' indicate that the row should not exist because of the stated reason)

```
desired_table
-----+--------+----------+-------------
  id |  name  | child_id | visited_ids
-----+--------+----------+-------------
  a  | A1, B1 |    c     | {'a', 'b'}
  a  | A1, B2 |    c     | {'a', 'b'}
  a  | A1, B3 |    a     | {'a', 'b'}  <-- 'a' was visited
  b  | B1, C1 |    d     | {'b', 'c'}
  b  | B2, C1 |    d     | {'b', 'c'}
  b  | B3, A1 |    b     | {'b', 'a'}  <-- 'b' was visited
  c  | C1, D1 |    a     | {'c', 'd'}
  c  | C1, D2 |    b     | {'c', 'd'}
  d  | D1, A1 |    b     | {'d', 'a'}
  d  | D2, B1 |    c     | {'d', 'b'}
  d  | D2, B2 |    c     | {'d', 'b'}
  d  | D2, B3 |    a     | {'d', 'b'}
```

The rows in this new table are to be repeatedly 'join' to my_table again so as to produce this output.
(Rows marked with '<--' indicate that the row should not exist because of the stated reason)

```
desired_table
-----+------------+----------+----------------
  id |    name    | child_id |   visited_ids
-----+------------+----------+----------------
  a  | A1, B1, C1 |    d     | {'a', 'b', 'c'}
  a  | A1, B2, C1 |    d     | {'a', 'b', 'c'}
  b  | B1, C1, D1 |    a     | {'b', 'c', 'd'}
  b  | B1, C1, D2 |    b     | {'b', 'c', 'd'}  <-- 'b' was visited
  b  | B2, C1, D1 |    a     | {'b', 'c', 'd'}
  b  | B2, C1, D2 |    b     | {'b', 'c', 'd'}  <-- 'b' was visited
  c  | C1, D1, D1 |    a     | {'c', 'd', 'd'}  <-- 'd' was visited
  c  | C1, D1, D2 |    b     | {'c', 'd', 'd'}  <-- 'd' was visited
  c  | C1, D2, B1 |    c     | {'c', 'd', 'b'}  <-- 'c' was visited
  c  | C1, D2, B2 |    c     | {'c', 'd', 'b'}  <-- 'c' was visited
  c  | C1, D2, B3 |    a     | {'c', 'd', 'b'}
  d  | D1, A1, B1 |    c     | {'d', 'a', 'b'}
  d  | D1, A1, B2 |    c     | {'d', 'a', 'b'}
  d  | D1, A1, B3 |    a     | {'d', 'a', 'b'}
  d  | D2, B1, C1 |    d     | {'d', 'b', 'c'}  <-- 'd' was visited
  d  | D2, B2, C1 |    d     | {'d', 'b', 'c'}  <-- 'd' was visited
  d  | D2, B3, A1 |    b     | {'d', 'b', 'a'}
```

... so on and so forth.
Rows that can still be 'joined' will be joined until they have no more children.
Rows that can no longer be joined will remain as is.

Answer (score 1):

One problem of your example is, that you have an endless loop there `(a,A1,b) -> (b,B3,a) -> (a,A1,b)` which is a bit tricky to detect.

But this (and peufeu's link) should get you started:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (id, names, child_id, path)
AS
(
   SELECT id, array[name], child_id, array[id] as path
   FROM mapping
   WHERE id = 'a'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c.id, p.names||c.name, c.child_id, p.path||c.id
   FROM mapping c
   JOIN hierarchy p ON p.child_id = c.id AND NOT (p.path @> (p.path||c.id))
)
SELECT *
FROM hierarchy
ORDER BY 1
```

It does not create the "visited_ids" column as you want it though

Answer (score 0):

Your post corresponds perfectly to a WITH RECURSIVE query :

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html